Adding horizontal rules with distance accuracy between themselves and contents around them

I am trying to write a custom code to provide writing rules with the following

Has number of lines, spacing, thickness, and color as optional arguments
Spacing above and below the generated lines should be exactly as the spacing among lines themselves

Requirement 1
The output above for is for the default \baselineskip in book document class, which is as desired. However, changing the spacing among lines (argument #2) means the typeset distances is not as desired, but very close. I think there is something about fine-tuning the vertical distances I am not aware of, which I want to be corrected
Requirement 2
Using tikz and recommending packages to get similar results
My MWE
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\writingRules}{O{4} O{\baselineskip} O{0.4pt} O{gray}}
{%
    \par%
    \vspace{\dimexpr \baselineskip - #2 + 0.15pt \relax}%
    \noindent%
    \foreach \linenum in {1, ..., #1}
    {%
        \par%
        \vspace{\dimexpr \baselineskip - #2 \relax}%
        \noindent%
        {\color{#4}\rlap{\rule{\linewidth}{#3}}}%
        \rlap{\linenum}%
    }
}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\smash{\rlap{\rule{\linewidth}{0.1pt}}}%
Text

\writingRules[5]

\noindent%
\smash{\rlap{\rule{\linewidth}{0.1pt}}}%
Text

\end{document}

